# Inconsistent dimensions in Python (sometimes shows 1D and sometimes 3D)

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist, data-science

I have a list and each element of the list is a 2D matrix.

```
np.shape(mylist)
>>(5000,)

np.shape(mylist[0])
>>(62,62)


type(mylist)
>> list

type(mylist[0])
>> numpy.ndarray
```

Now, I'm trying to create a list of indexes that appear in the index list:

```
y_train = [mylist[i] for i in index]
```

The problem is that sometimes it shows a 1D shape and sometimes 3D (e.g. (nx,) or (nx,ny,nz))

For example:

```
yy = []
yy.append(mylist[17])
yy.append(mylist[1381])

print(np.shape(yy))

>> (2,)

yy = []
yy.append(mylist[17])
yy.append(mylist[1380])

print(np.shape(yy))

>> (2, 513, 513)
```

Any idea why? maybe the fact that mylist[17] and mylist[1380] are of the same shape and mylist[17] and mylist[1381] are of different shape?

Comment: Yes. Also, why are you even calling `np.shape` on a python list? You should use `len` for that. Reserve using shape on numpy arrays. Also don't use `numpy.shape()`, use `ndarray.shape` directly.

Comment: What output you would expect to have at line 4?

Comment: `np.shape(alist)` first turns `alist` into a `numpy` array, and then returns the `shape` attribute.  If the elements of the list all have the same 2d shape, then list-turned-array will be 3d, if they differ in shape, it will be a 1d object dtype array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a simple case where 2 arrays have different shapes:

```
In [204]: alist = [np.ones((2,3),int), np.zeros((1,3),int)]
In [205]: alist
Out[205]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0]])]
In [206]: len(alist)
Out[206]: 2
In [207]: np.shape(alist)
Out[207]: (2,)
In [208]: alist.shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-6ab8dc5f9201> in <module>()
----> 1 alist.shape

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
In [209]: np.array(alist)
Out[209]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0]])], dtype=object)
```

A list has a `len`, but not a `shape`.  `np.shape` first turns the input into an array.  So the differences in dimensions are differences in how `np.array` constructs an array from your list.  In this case it constructs an `object` dtype array.  In many ways this array is more like a list than a nd array.

With two arrays of the same shape, `np.array` creates a nd array.

```
In [210]: alist = [np.ones((2,3),int), np.zeros((2,3),int)]
In [211]: alist
Out[211]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]])]
In [212]: len(alist)
Out[212]: 2
In [213]: np.shape(alist)
Out[213]: (2, 2, 3)
In [214]: np.array(alist)
Out[214]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

`alist` still doesn't have a shape` attribute.